# ASP file upload capture file before it is submitted

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I am using the basic simple asp fileupload, as follows:

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="uplNewFile" Multiple="multiple"/>
```

I am trying to achieve the following:

A user hits the choose file button

They then select a file (file1) and click the 'choose' button

Then they select the choose file button again, and select another file (file2)

The user then hits the upload button

In this circumstance I want both files to be uploaded to the server eg file1 and file2, but it seems that only the newest one is.

Is it possible to keep the original file, and then add the new one to it.

I assume I need a way to intercept the 'choose file' event, but is it possible to do this? From all I have read on the fileupload button, there is not much you can do with it, it seems to be controlled by the users browser?

Answer (score 0):

You don't select files 1 by 1, the user needs to select all the files he wants to upload in 1 go, by holding in Ctrl while selecting the files.

You can then process the files on the server side using the 
uplNewFile.PostedFiles collection and do what you need to do.

Comment: @CarlBI understand that, but I do not think that is a very user friendly implementation and think it would be better to implement the way I have described above

Comment: Another seriously hacky way of doing it is to drop multiple upload controls on your page and hide all but the first one (style="display:none") . Then after you selected a file for the first one, you hide it and make the 2nd one visible.  and so on and so on.  And then you click your upload button to upload the whole lot.

Comment: I like the idea but I am not going to use that - I am sure it can be done though - If I find a way I will post it